# How to display the AlertDialog with white color transparent background theme in Android?

Tags: android, styles, android-alertdialog, android-theme

I am using Alert-dialog in my application. I want to display the Alert-dialog with white color with a transparent background colour. What style do I have to apply to support all  devices from Android version 14 and above? (Higher version). Even some devices display an Alert-dialog box with a black background theme.

Can you anyone tell me that what style I have to use?

Comment: Inside `/res/values/style.xml` you can set theme for entire application.